# My list python code is producing a sum other than what is intended. Python

Tags: python

I am trying to code a program that take user input of orders and converts it to a list that I can then produce a sum based on the number of each word in the list. However, my code keeps producing a a sum that is not correct for the provided list. For example, if I enter Water Nachos Water Cheeseburger the intended sum is 24, but my code is producing 39 as the answer. Why is this and what is a potential fix?

```
x = input("What are your orders?")
orders = list(x.split())
sum = 0
for i in orders:
      if i == "Nachos":
       sum+=6
      if i == "Pizza":
       sum+=6
      if i == "Water":
       sum+=4
      if i == "Cheeseburger":
       sum+=10
      else:
        sum+=5
print(sum)
```

I expected a sum of 24, but got a sum of 39.

Comment: You want the `if`s to be `elif`s (except the first one). Right now, you have 3 if statements and 1 if/else, so anything other then Cheeseburger will also get the +5 from the `else` of cheeseburger. See [here](https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-if-else-statements.php)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! I guess I did not fully understand this concept and need to go back and review.

Comment: It seems that you got the *fix* already. Great.  BTW - better not use the *built-in*  ```sum``` as the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The last else part is only for the if condition `i == "Cheeseburger"`
So `sum+=5 will gets executed for all the other conditions.
You can just use if else if

```
x = input("What are your orders?")
orders = list(x.split())
sum = 0
for i in orders:
      if i == "Nachos":
       sum+=6
      elif i == "Pizza":
       sum+=6
      elif i == "Water":
       sum+=4
      elif i == "Cheeseburger":
       sum+=10
      else:
        sum+=5
print(sum)
```